# What happens when a Marine or Pirate goes after a bounty

Tags: one-piece

In One Piece notorious pirates have a bounty on their heads with Luffy getting his after defeating Arlong.

It seems obvious to me that the Marines would be the ones who do the payouts since they are the one who produce the wanted posters, but what happens when a Marine like Smoker goes after a pirate? Do they get the bounty or some other reward?

And what about other pirates such with the case when Buggy and Alvida were about to kill Luffy in Roguetown, would the Marines pay out the bounty to them if they came to claim it (considering that by killing or bringing in another pirate is doing the Marine's job for them)

Comment: case point Blackbeard runaway after defeating Bonney instead of waiting for her bounty from Marines . . . .

Answer (score 2):

We haven't yet seen the details of a bounty being collected, but it seems incredibly unlikely that the marines would pay a pirate the bounty for defeating or capturing another pirate, as all pirates are by definition wanted criminals who are to be arrested on recognition, as in the world of One Piece, merely flying a black flag and declaring yourself a pirate is a crime. This seems backed up by when Blackbeard captured Jewellery Bonney and tried to exchange her with the world government, they responded by sending a warship with an angry Akainu on board.

It also seems unlikely that they would give the bounties to marines who are carrying out their duties, and would have different rewards in place, but it is perfectly possible that marines can and do earn bounty rewards.

The main groups that seem eligible to receive bounties seem to be:

- Bounty Hunters
- Mercenaries
- Armies and soldiers who report to a single nation instead of the world government
- Assassins
- Warlords

Obviously for the average concerned citizen in One Piece, capturing or defeating someone with a large bounty is impossible, as bounties tend to be at least somewhat correlated with strength. A notable exception is a young Nico Robin, who had a large bounty long before she had any significant combat strength, so was always on the run and fearing being turned in.

Anyone not considered a criminal who has the luck/power to capture or kill a bounty holder while not working for the world government seems to be guaranteed the bounty, so almost anyone except for marines, revolutionaries, pirates and other criminals.

Answer (score 0):

1. As we see Luffy first got a bounty of 30.000.000 Beli after defeating Arlong. He got this especially because he beat this marine guy who had deas with Arlong (don't remember the name) and that guy wanted Luffy `Dead or Alive`. So the marine checked Luffys enemys - Buggy (15 Mio), Don Creek (17 Mio), Arlong (20 Mio) - based on them he got his 30 Mio.
2. Sure, I think, the marine has to pay that bounty because they are obvisously the good ones and want them to imprison.
3. Marines guys won't get the price, the will get some promotion or a title - like we saw after defeating Crocodile with Smoker.
4. Since Pirates and Marines are the biggest foes and the marine want to destroy all piracy they would catch the pirates instead of being thankful.

Comment: do you have any canonical source to refute what you're saying?

Answer (score -1):

I think they did not get the bounty on pirate head. They are working under government. They must salary and get promotion on the basis of their success and the power they got like coby.

The pirate hunter get the bounty when the caught the pirate or kill the pirate.

Comment: While common sense tells me you're probably not far off, do you have any references to add to your answer to make it more convincing?

Answer (score -1):

So if a sichibukai kills a pirate will he get the bounty.Sichibukai aren't targeted by the marines so will they wait for the marines to come and collect the bounty.

Comment: Is this headcanon or do you have any canonical sources to refute this?